# REGEX to format decimals using superscript in MVC4 Razor / Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, currency

I am trying to format currency decimals using superscript, e.g. $1.<sup>08</sup> instead of $1.08. Currently, my model currency variable (assume `1.08` value) shows as `$1.08` using a model template and MVC4 Razor / Javascript:

```
[Range(0, 10000)]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }

@{
    @Html.Display(model => model.Price)
}
```

Instead, I tried to extract and format decimals using REGEX, but it still displays as `$1.08` (P.S. currency localization not important at this time):

```
@{
    var numRaw = Model.Price;
    var numSty = numRaw.ToString.Replace("(?<=\\.)([^.]*$)", "<sup>$1</sup>");
    @Html.Raw(numSty);
}
```

Note the double backslash `\\.` escape. The search expression seems to [work correctly](https://regex101.com/r/iZ1qM6/1).

Am I doing something wrong in the `"<sup>$1</sup>"` replace string?

Comment: There shouldn't be a `/` on the front of your regex.

Comment: Shouldn't you be making the cents part the superscript rather than the dollars part? As you have in your example at the top

Comment: I am not convinced your search expression works correctly, try add several together: "1.08 1.09 1.10", it will only match the last one

Comment: -AndrewB: I removed the `/` at the beginning and also added a missing ToString(). before the Replace(). For strings like `"1.08 1.09 1.10"`, you are correct that it captures decimals only in the last term but it should not be an issue in my case as I create the string directly from a decimal. For the `<sup>$1</sup>`, I thought `$1` referred to the second parenthesized group, i.e. `([^.]*$)` since the first group begins with a `?`.

Comment: I am not familar with razor or asp.net, and I could not find documentation quickly so this may be a stupid question, but does "Replace" actually handle regex or only string literals? Worth checking if you don't know.

Comment: Absolutely right, @AndrewB! It should be `Regex.Replace(...)`.

Comment: -AndrewB, -Simon McKenzie: right on the money! Need to use `Regex`. I have a working solution. -AndrewB please post an answer so I can accept. I will edit my question with the working solution. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Alfred I don't actually know how to format the correct answer, I could only point you to a possible error. When you have your correct solution you should write it up as an answer to the question and Tick it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @AndrewB and @SimonMcKenzie, Regex.Replace() must be used for Razor to work. The following code displays $1.<sup>08</sup> as expected:

```
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions

@Html.Raw("$"+Regex.Replace(Math.Round(Model.Price,2).ToString(), "(?<=\\.)([^.]*$)", "<sup>$1</sup>"));
```